# Can I write charName 'a' or 'A' = "Albert"?

Tags: haskell

Following is the example I have reproduced:

> charName :: Char -> String
>   charName 'a'  = "Albert"
>   charName 'b' = "Broseph"
>   charName 'c' = "Cecil"
>   charName  x = "Not defined yet"

Can I further modify above mentioned code to something like below (will not compile):

> charName :: Char -> String
>   charName 'a' or 'A' = "Albert"
>   charName 'b' or 'B' = "Broseph"
>   charName 'c' or 'C' = "Cecil"
>   charName  x or X= "Not defined yet"

In order to get "Albert" if charName 'a' or charName 'A'   given.

Please guide how to write above mentioned code in possible shortest manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is:

```
charName :: Char -> String
charName ch 
 | ch `elem` "aA" = "Albert"
 | ch `elem` "bB" = "Broseph"
 | ch `elem` "cC" = "Cecil"
 | otherwise = "Not defined yet"
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Mihai's answer, you could use a case statement, which allows you to pattern match without having to define an extra function:

```
import Data.Char (toLower)

charName :: Char -> String
charName c = case toLower c of
              'a' -> "Albert"
              'b' -> "Broseph"
              _   -> "Not defined yet"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `toLower` from `Data.Char` and function composition. One solution is

```
charName :: Char -> String
charName = charName' . toLower
    where
        charName' 'a' = "Albert"
        charName' 'b' = "Broseph"
        charName' 'c' = "Cecil"
        charName' _   = "Not defined yet"
```

Also, for the last case, if you want to return an error, why don't you use `undefined` or `error error_msg`?

Comment: @augustss Sir, can you please retest it and guide. I am getting this error while trying to load : baby.hs:63:26: Not in scope: `toLower'
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: @Optimight you need to stick `import Data.Char` at the beginning of your file

Comment: @Optimight: I've edited the code, it had to be just "charName" instead of "charName c".

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.List (find)

charName :: Char -> String
charName c = maybe "Not defined yet" snd $ find (elem c . fst)
  [ ( "aA", "Arthur" )
  , ( "bB", "Broseph" )
  , ( "cC", "Cecil" )
  ]
```

An explanation of what was used:

- `fst` and `snd`: extract the first or second element of a tuple, respectively
- `Data.List.find`: find an element of the list which satisfies a given predicate
- `maybe`: deal with `Maybe` values. `find` produces a `Maybe` result, so you have to handle the case of failure. In this case, I chose (as you did) the string "Not defined yet"
- `elem`: determine if something is contained in a given list (usage similar to Landei's answer). Recall that `String` is represented as a list of `Char`.
- function composition: the `.` in the expression `(elem c . fst)` composes the two functions. That is, it takes its input tuple, accesses the first element (which is a `String`), and then determines if `c` is one of the characters in that string. Function composition is read from right to left.
- `$`: the dollar sign is function application. It is mainly used to avoid parens. There are various StackOverflow answers that detail the uses of `.` and `$`.